# HTML: CSS: Place element somewhere by class

Tags: html, css

Say I have 6 elements:

```
<img src="..." class="a"/>
<img src="..." class="b"/>
<img src="..." class="c"/>
<img src="..." class="d"/>
<img src="..." class="e"/>
<img src="..." class="f"/>
```

which are **not** necessarily images like shown above, but can be any element, like some `<div>`.

Is it possible to create a grid of 3x2 and place each element of these in one container?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @squint could you please either provide a reference or sample code? I couldn't find this and don't know what it's called.

Comment: If you're saying you want to do it dynamically via JavaScript, and you don't know where to start, I'd probably just start with some beginner's tutorials. Mozilla Developer Network has useful information that should get you going: [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/JavaScript)

Comment: @squint Thanks. Actually I prefer a css way of doing it. Does that exist?

Comment: Oh, so you don't mean a literal `<table>` element. I misunderstood. You have JavaScript and jQuery tags on your question, so you should probably remove those and let the CSS experts handle it. Just to be clear, you don't want a table, but want a 3x2 layout of a particular set of elements that are otherwise just siblings of each other. Is that right?

Comment: @squint To be honest I just want something that looks like a table. I don't necessarily need a table tag per se, but if there's a way with a table tag, I'm happy with it too. Anything that would create aligned elements at some specific text position  (i.e., defined by text indicator, and not x and y coordinates) is fine.

Comment: Oh, so you can edit the HTML? I feel like I'm missing some details.

Comment: @squint Yes. I have full control on the file I'm editing.

Comment: lol, sorry, I thought you were saying you were stuck with the HTML in the question and needed some sort of dynamic solution that would work with what you have. Tables are usually just for sets of data. Do you need consistent column/row sizes? Will the size of the individual elements differ? You'll probably have more success if you put these details in the question.

Comment: @squint I'm happy to add more info to the question, except that I'm not sure what to add there, because I want the question to be as abstract as possible to benefit others. The situation accurately is that I have a library (mapael) that creates a legend of a Javascript world map. The legend's elements can each have a css class. So I would like to spawn each of the legends elements in a table cell to align them the way I need. The elements are almost equal in width and height. I don't think that's a problem. What do you think?

Comment: What happens if you have three of `class="b"` and seven of `class="e"`?  It seems to me that (a) they should be using distinct `id` instead of class, or (b) the classes being different is irrelevant and, in fact, should probably all be the _same_ class (as in "here is the class of things I want arranged in a grid")

Comment: @StephenP conceptually you're right, but I can give each legend element a class name I choose. That I know, and I'm trying to find a way to exploit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using classes as you pretend, mixing a lot of elements as you don't know which will be used.

### option #1 - using `flexbox`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:100vh
}
.a,
.b,
.c,
.d,
.e,
.f {
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 3);
  height:50%;
  background: lightblue;  
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div class="a">div with Class A</div>
  <img class="b" src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" />
  <span class="c">span with Class C</span>
  <article class="d">article with Class D</article>
  <div class="e">div with Class E</div>
  <section class="f">Div with Class F</section>
</div>
```

### option #2 - using `inline-block`

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  height:100%
}
#ib {
  font-size: 0;
  height:100%
}
.a,
.b,
.c,
.d,
.e,
.f {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background:lightblue;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height:50%;
  font-size: 16px
}
```

```html
<div id="ib">
  <div class="a">div with Class A</div>
  <img class="b" src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" />
  <span class="c">span with Class C</span>
  <article class="d">article with Class D</article>
  <div class="e">div with Class E</div>
  <section class="f">Div with Class F</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to do this without referring to `img` in the css code? It doesn't have to be img actually... They can be anything, and the only thing I know about these objects is their class names.

Comment: I just use `img` but yes you can with just class no matter the element.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist consider: `<div class="grid-container"> <div class="grid-item>...</div> <div class="grid-item> ... </div> ...etc... </div>` then write your css in terms of those classes instead of the `div` and `img` tags.

Comment: Could you explain what the img in your css code does then? Doesn't that restrict your code to img only?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist was just for the sake of make the demo simple, but if you really want need to use class, then instead of `img` in css, you need to have `.a,.b,.c,.d.e,.f,.h { properties: values }`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that and give you feedback soon!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist do you want me to update the answer?

Comment: @dippas in your code, you use `calc(100% / 3)` which could lead to the Fractional Pixels problem. The 3rd item could drop to the next line, then it would be a 2x3 grid.

Comment: @J.Joe nop it will never happen that's the beauty of calc.. If done correctly with the rest of other properties

Comment: @dippas How can you be so sure? Where is it documented?

Comment: @J.Joe instead of showing specs, here is an article from CSS -Tricks,  - [article](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using CSS :nth-child() Selector and you can move required elements to next line and form matrix

```
    <div class="a">1</div>
    <div class="b">2</div>
    <div class="c">3</div>
    <div class="d">4</div>
    <div class="e">5</div>
    <div class="f">6</div>


      div {
        display: inline;
      }

      div:nth-child(4) {
        display: inline;
      }

      div:nth-child(3):after {
        content: "\a";
        white-space: pre;
      }
```

Hope this is helpful for you :)

codepen URL for reference -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzNmBz

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and provide feedback first thing tomorrow.

Comment: sure @TheQuantumPhysicist

Answer (score 0):

Note the **th** tag is for headings, **tr** tag for rows and **td** tag is where you need to write your data. Hope this helps

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

`

Comment: Don't use tables to do layout. Use tables to contain tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

The generic approach to this is to use a class for the container in which the items will be laid out, and a class for each item that will be in the container.

This sample mostly takes the form of @dippas' *"using flexbox"* example, but the CSS styles are not particular to any set of `id`s or `class`es ... you can attach the additional class if necessary.  `<div class="a">...</div>` could become `<div class="a grid-item">...</div>` or omit the class `a` as I do.

You can see you just attach the `grid-item` class to any sort of thing you want.

This can also be styled using the `inline-block` method if that's preferable.

UI frameworks commonly take this approach, where you just attach the appropriate class(es) to your elements to give them the layout / style desired.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-item {
  flex: 1 0 calc((100% / 3) - 4px);
  height: 50%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: 1px dotted burlywood;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div     class="grid-item">A</div>
  <div     class="grid-item">B</div>
  <span    class="grid-item">C</span>
  <img     class="grid-item" src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" />
  <section class="grid-item">Section E</section>
  <div     class="grid-item">F</div>
</div><!-- grid-container -->
```

You can even omit the class for the items if everything in the grid-container will be laid out like this...

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* select all immediate children of the .grid-container */
.grid-container > * {
  flex: 1 0 calc((100% / 3) - 4px);
  height: 50%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: 1px dotted burlywood;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>div A</div>
  <div>div B</div>
  <span>span C</span>
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" />
  <section>section E</section>
  <div>div F</div>
</div><!-- grid-container -->
```